# Action has more than one parameter that was specified or inferred as bound from request body. Only one parameter per action may be bound from body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Error : Action has more than one parameter that was specified or inferred as bound from request body. Only one parameter per action may be bound from body
.netcore

When i wrote a new httpPost method  with 2 parameters of my .net core project and getting above error. how can i solve this.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] UserBO userBO, [FromBody] SiteCode siteCode)
        {
            try
            {

                await _userService.CreateUserAsync(userBO, siteCode);

                return Created(nameof(Get), userBO);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return HandleException(ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, the error message is pretty clear - you can only use `[FromBody]` with one parameter, basically. It's not clear how you expected this to work - surely the body is *either* a `UserBO` *or* a `SiteCode`, but it can't really be both. What does the body look like in this case? Perhaps you need a new type that contains both a `UserBO` and a `SiteCode`?

Comment: You can add multiple MIME attachments to your POST.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Comment: when i create a user, add a record to another table (siteUSer table). so i need add two parameters. i don't know what should put there, that's why i put [frombody] before both

Comment: Can you pass `SiteCode` as part of the path?  It seems like it is a required field.  If a User is created in the context of a site, that would be a RESTful way to describe the relationship.  If they are NOT created in the context of the site, then a wrapping object is ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a new Model which contains userBO and siteCode:

Model:

```
public class USModel
    {
        public UserBO userBO { get; set; }
        public SiteCode siteCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] USModel uSModel)
        {
            try
            {

                await _userService.CreateUserAsync(uSModel.userBO, uSModel.siteCode);

                return Created(nameof(Get), uSModel.userBO);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return HandleException(ex);
            }
        }
```

json format:

```
{
    "userBO":
    {
        ...
    },
    "siteCode":
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error on a .NET 7 web Api controller being migrated from .NET 4.8.  In the original controller there was a public void method consumed by the actions of the controller.  The error was occurring in Program.cs:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: default,
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I changed the method to private void which fixed it.  I don't know why routing was trying to include the method as an endpoint as there wasn't a routing attribute.